# Magento 2: change product page layout from admin

Tags: magento-2.1, layout

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and  I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I've changed the layout of my homepage to *2 columns with left bar* from `Content -> Pages`. I need to do the same for **the product page**.

As can be seen in the image below, I don't have this option for the product page:

[image]

Can I enable changing this layout from `Content -> Pages`? If not is there an alternative (best way) to get the same result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For product page layout change there is no option in admin (*unless you want it for a particular product, for that you can choose layout in edit product page under design tab*), you can do it using xml file. Follow below to change layout using xml

> Copy `catalog_product_view.xml` from
>   vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout to your theme.

and in this file you can change layout in below code

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

</page>
```

Comment: I would like to use the exact same layout for the product page and homepage. Where can I find the homepage layout file to copy its content _to _ the product page?

Comment: use above code it will set the same 2 columns with left bar layout for your product page

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this

**1. Do it programmaticaly & do changes into your own theme which will apply the changes to every products page you are entering from
backend. `(Recommanded)`**

Go to this place into your **Magento_root**

`magento_root\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout`

Copy a file 'catalog_product_view.xml' & put it at

`magento_root\app\design\frontend\Your_Package\your_theme\Magento_Catalog\layout`
Find this code

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

And replace it with

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

**2. When You are entering the products do it there by selecting the layout `But it will remain onto that products page only`.**

> Go to Products >> Catalog >> Add New Product/Edit Product >> Design
>   Layout

Select **`2 Columns with left bar`**